# Can Application class be package-private?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

My Application class code:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Process;

import com.squareup.leakcanary.LeakCanary;

public class SampleApplication extends Application {

    public SampleApplication() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
            // This process is dedicated to LeakCanary for heap analysis.
            // You should not init your app in this process.
            return;
        }
        LeakCanary.install(this);
        // Normal app init code...
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        System.exit(0);
        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());

        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

**Android Studio 3.1 Canary 7 --> Analyze --> Inspect Code --> OK:**

Declaration access can be weaker inspection

1 warning: SampleApplication can be package-private

*Can Application class be package-private or it's lint error?*

Comment: Yes it can be package private

Comment: @UdeshUK, [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html): "The Application class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated **before any other class** when the process for your application/package is created". Does it mean that Application class must be public?

Comment: As referenced by Alex, from Java documentation - "A class may be declared with the modifier public, in which case that class is visible to all classes everywhere. If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be package private. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678457/what-does-can-be-package-local-mean-idea-inspection) question in Stack overflow and also read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to learn how to control access to members of a class.

For a further explanation: inhering from Application alows you to start the app without a main method (the class which inherits acts as the main class). It needs to be public if you're accessing other packages with it. If not, you can set it as package-private.

Comment: [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html): "The Application class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated **before any other class** when the process for your application/package is created". Does it mean that Application class must be public?

Comment: @AlexanderSavin Inhering from Application alows you to start the app without a main method (the class which inherits acts as the main class). It needs to be public if you're accessing other packages with it. If not, you can set it as package-private.

Comment: Alex Cuadrón thanks, I accepted your answer, please add your comment to your answer

Comment: @AlexanderSavin done, thanks for selecting as answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `public` modifier to your inaccessible class